# Using a user-defined list in table-service query

Tags: python, azure, tableservicescontext

I have a large list of partition keys, corresponding to which I want to receive data from the table.

For a single value, filter="PartitionKey eq 'KeyValue'" works.
But I want to get all the data corresponding to PartitionKey entries in my_list.

```
c_table = table_service.query_entities('c', filter="PartitionKey in my_list")
```

What I've tried using the 'in' keyword gives an error.
Also, I'm unable to find any official documentation citing using list in the table-service query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since `in` is not supported, you will need to use `or`. Something like:

```
c_table = table_service.query_entities('c', filter="(PartitionKey eq 'list_item_1') or (PartitionKey eq 'list_item_2') or (PartitionKey eq 'list_item_3')")
```

Comment: But I have a large list of values(~10k) against which I need to extract the data. Using  'or' for such a case isn't feasible.

Comment: In that case, one possible option is to break the list into small sub lists and issue multiple queries. If the elements in the list follow a particular pattern, you can use `greater than equal to (ge)` and `less than equal to (le)` operators.